# Subclassing NSObject in Swift - Best Practice with Initializers

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, subclass, nsobject

Here is the layout of an example Class, can someone guide me on what's best practice when creating a subclass of NSObject?

```
class MyClass: NSObject {

    var someProperty: NSString! = nil

    override init() {
        self.someProperty = "John"
        super.init()
    }

    init(fromString string: NSString) {
        self.someProperty = string
        super.init()
    }

}
```

Is this correct, am I following best practice here?

I wonder if I'm correctly setting up the initializers (one that sets the string to a default, and one which I can pass in a string)?

Should I call `super.init()` at the end of each of the initializers?

Should my more **specific** (the one that takes a string) initializer simply call `self.init()` at the end rather than `super.init()`?

What is the right way to set up the initializers in Swift when subclassing `NSObject`? - and how should I call the super init ?

This question (albeit in Objective C) suggests you should have an init, which you always call and simply set the properties in more specific inits: [Objective-C Multiple Initialisers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026914/objective-c-multiple-initialisers)

Comment: *The Swift Programming Language* has an [entire chapter on initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_306), covering inheritance, designated vs. convenience initializers, and so on. The process is significantly different than Objective-C (and to me feels more complex/nuanced), so definitely read that to understand better what to do.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I'm not Swift ninja but I would write `MyClass` as:

```
class MyClass: NSObject {
    
    var someProperty: NSString // no need (!). It will be initialised from controller 
    
    init(fromString string: NSString) {
        self.someProperty = string
        super.init() // can actually be omitted in this example because will happen automatically.
    }
    
    convenience override init() {
        self.init(fromString:"John") // calls above mentioned controller with default name
    }        
}
```

---

See the [initialization section of the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_306)

Comment: What if you want to init multiple properties? One is a string, another is a NSNumber, an array, etc.....

Comment: @Supertecnoboff you would add each of them into the initialiser method, ie: 

```init(with name: NSString, age: NSNumber, children: [NSString]) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.children = children
        super.init()
    }```

Answer (score 2):

If someProperty can be nil, then I think you want to define the property as:

```
var someProperty: NSString?
```

This also eliminates the need for a custom initializer (at least, for this property), since the property doesn't require a value at initialization time.

Answer (score 0):

In complement to the answers, a good idea is to call super.init() *before* other statements. I think it's a stronger requirement in Swift because allocations are implicit.

Comment: You cannot call `super.init()` prior to initializing non-optional fields that do not have a default value in their declaration.  In this case it would work because the property is an optional type: `NSString!`.